# how to change keycloak template theme [the actual keycloak administration console theme]

Tags: themes, keycloak

I want to know how to change keycloak template theme,

I have to change the actual keycloak administration console theme not the login/admin/account/email theme :

keycloak theme

[image: 1]

In the admin console, I can select the theme of the login/admin/account/email pages, but what i want is to change the actual theme for this admin console

i hope i was clear enough this is my first time posting a question.

Comment: Did you try to go to the master realm and then select themes, and Admin Console theme?

Comment: yes, but if I select the master realm, the changes only apply to the master and not to the whole project

Comment: you need to apply to master and the remaining realms